# How can I click a button on a form in a TWebrowser in Delphi

Tags: html, delphi, web, submit

I have this HTML Code:

```
<span class="button field_full_in_single_col"><button type="submit">Sign In</button></span>
```

How can I login to the application when I click the submit button?

Comment: More direct would be to skip the button and just submit the form. Even more direct than that would be to skip the HTML entirely and just use TIdHTTP to send the same POST request that the browser would with the form's data.

Answer (score 3):

You need to query the `TWebBrowser.Document` for the [`IHTMLDocument2`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface and then either:

1. drill through the DOM locating the desired button's [`IHTMLElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752279%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface, and then you can call its [`click()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752277%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.
2. locate the [`IHTMLFormElement`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752432%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) interface of the desired button's parent webform in the [`IHTMLDocument2.forms`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752591%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) collection, and then call its [`submit()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa752442%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method.